# run two motors in turns without using delay()

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, motor, millis

I googled solutions and tried, but I still cannot get it working.

I've tried BlinkwithoutDelay.

I feel it is very confusing to track timing of two motors (i.e., step, direction, speed) for the following routine loop:

- step 1: run motorA_forward() for 10 seconds;
- step 2: run motorAB_stop() for 1 seconds;
- step 3: run motorB_backward() for 3 seconds
- step 4: run motorAB_stop() for 1 seconds
- step 5: run motorA_backward() for 10 seconds
- step 6: run motorAB_stop() for 1 seconds

Please help me on this!! I really appreciate your time and comments.

Thank you.

The following is my working code.

```C++
// ----------LIBRARIES--------------

#include <Wire.h>
#include <LIDARLite.h>
LIDARLite myLidarLite;


// ----------CONSTANTS--------------

const int motorA_pin_1 = 8;           // the pin numbers for the motors
const int motorA_pin_2 = 11;
const int motorA_pin_speed = 9;
const int motorB_pin_1 = 12;
const int motorB_pin_2 = 13;
const int motorB_pin_speed = 10;

//------------VARIABLES--------------

byte motorA_state_1 = LOW;             // used to record whether the motots are on or off
byte motorA_state_2 = LOW;             // LOW = off
byte motorB_state_1 = LOW;             
byte motorB_state_2 = LOW;             

int currentMillis               = 0;     // stores the value of millis() in each iteration of loop()
int motorA_Forward_Interval     = 5000;  // will store last time the motor was moved
int motorA_Backward_Interval    = 5000; // will store last time the motor was moved
int motorA_Stop_Interval        = 2000;  // will store last time the motor was moved
int motorB_Stop_Interval        = 2000;  // will store last time the motor was moved
int motorAB_BreakTime_Interval  = 2000;

unsigned long motorA_Forward_Timer      = 0;     // will store last time motorA start was updated
unsigned long motorA_Backward_Timer     = 0;     // will store last time motorA start was updated
unsigned long motorB_Forward_Timer      = 0;     // will store last time motorA start was updated
unsigned long motorB_Backward_Timer     = 0;     // will store last time motorA start was updated
unsigned long BreakTime_timer   = 0;     // will store last time motorA/B break time was updated


//------------INITIALIZATION--------------

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myLidarLite.begin();

  pinMode(motorA_pin_1,OUTPUT);         // set the motor pins as output:
  pinMode(motorA_pin_2,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(motorA_pin_speed,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(motorB_pin_1,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(motorB_pin_2,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(motorB_pin_speed,OUTPUT);


}

//------------LOOPING----------------------
// Notice that none of the action happens in loop() apart from reading millis()
// It just calls the functions that have the action code

void loop()
{
    Serial.println(myLidarLite.distance());

    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    motorA_forward();  // for 10 seconds
    motorAB_stop();    // for 1 seconds
    motorB_backward(); // for 3 seconds
    motorAB_stop();    // for 1 seconds
    motorA_backward(); // for 10 seconds
    motorAB_stop();    // for 1 seconds

}

//------------SUBROUTINE----------------------


void motorA_forward()
{   
  if(currentMillis - motorA_Forward_Timer <= motorA_Forward_Interval)
  {
    motorA_state_1 = HIGH;   // Turn motor A on - backward
    motorA_state_2 = LOW;  // 
    motorB_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor B off
    motorB_state_2 = LOW;   // 

    analogWrite(motorA_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_1,motorA_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_2,motorA_state_2);
    analogWrite(motorB_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_1,motorB_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_2,motorB_state_2);

    motorA_Forward_Timer = currentMillis;
  }
}

void motorA_backward()
{
    if(currentMillis - motorA_Backward_Timer <= motorA_Backward_Interval)
  {
    motorA_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor A on - backward
    motorA_state_2 = HIGH;  // 
    motorB_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor B off
    motorB_state_2 = LOW;   // 

    analogWrite(motorA_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_1,motorA_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_2,motorA_state_2);
    analogWrite(motorB_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_1,motorB_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_2,motorB_state_2);

    motorA_Backward_Timer += currentMillis;
  }
}

void motorB_forward()
{
    motorA_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor A off
    motorA_state_2 = LOW;   // 
    motorB_state_1 = HIGH;  // Turn motor B on - forward
    motorB_state_2 = LOW;   // 

    analogWrite(motorA_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_1,motorA_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_2,motorA_state_2);
    analogWrite(motorB_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_1,motorB_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_2,motorB_state_2);

    motorB_Forward_Timer = currentMillis;
}

void motorB_backward()
{
    motorA_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor A off
    motorA_state_2 = LOW;   // 
    motorB_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor B on - backward
    motorB_state_2 = HIGH;  // 

    analogWrite(motorA_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_1,motorA_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_2,motorA_state_2);
    analogWrite(motorB_pin_speed,255);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_1,motorB_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_2,motorB_state_2);

    motorB_Backward_Timer = currentMillis;
}

void motorAB_stop()
{
    motorA_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor A off
    motorA_state_2 = LOW;   // 
    motorB_state_1 = LOW;   // Turn motor B off
    motorB_state_2 = LOW;  // 

    analogWrite(motorA_pin_speed,0);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_1,motorA_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorA_pin_2,motorA_state_2);
    analogWrite(motorB_pin_speed,0);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_1,motorB_state_1);
    digitalWrite(motorB_pin_2,motorB_state_2);

    BreakTime_timer = currentMillis;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```C++
int currentMillis               = 0;     // stores the value of millis() in each iteration of loop()
...

void loop()
{
    Serial.println(myLidarLite.distance());
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
```

You have **two** `currentMillis` variables. The global one never changes. You change a **different** one inside `loop`.

---

Remove the data definition. eg.

```C++
void loop()
{
    Serial.println(myLidarLite.distance());
    currentMillis = millis();  // change the global variable
```

---

Also make the **global** one unsigned long:

```C++
unsigned long currentMillis               = 0;     // stores the value of millis() in each iteration of loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example where Object Oriented Programming (OOP) can make your life so much easier.

The principle behind OOP is to define a *Class* which contains all the actions you want to perform on something - in this case a motor.  The *Class* contains all the instructions on how to do things like set the motor speed, the direction, start it, stop it, etc.

From that *Class* you then create *Objects*.  The beauty is there is only one *Class* which has the abstract concept of "Motor Control", but that *Class* is used to create one *Object* for each motor you want to control.

A *Class*, and hence the *Objects* derived from it, are all completely self contained, which makes it so much easier to manage.  All the variables associated with a single motor are wrapped up inside the *Class* and you don't need to worry about unique names for them all on a per-motor basis.

For example, you might define a class like this:

```
class Motor {
    private:
        int _speedPin;
        int _directionPin1;
        int _directionPin2;

    public:
        Motor(int sp, int dp1, int dp2) {
            _speedPin = sp;
            _directionPin1 = dp1;
            _directionPin2 = dp2;
        }
        void begin() {
            analogWrite(_speedPin, 0);
            pinMode(_directionPin1, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(_directionPin2, OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin2, LOW);
        }
        void forward() {
            digitalWrite(_directionPin1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin2, LOW);
        }
        void reverse() {
            digitalWrite(_directionPin1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin2, HIGH);
        }
        void speed(int speed) {
            analogWrite(_speedPin, speed);
        }
        void stop() {
            analogWrite(_speedPin, 0);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(_directionPin2, LOW);
        }
};
```

Everything you need to control a motor is in there.  Then you could use that to create two motor objects:

```
Motor leftMotor(3, 4, 5);
Motor rightMotor(6, 7, 8);
```

You provide the pins that control the motor to the *constructor* of the object - that is pin 3 is the speed pin of the first motor, and pins 4 and 5 are the direction control pins, etc.

You can now control the motors very simply.  Configure the pins by calling the begin function defined in the class above:

```
void setup() {
    leftMotor.begin();
    rightMotor.begin();
}
```

And now you can use similar decision making as normal to decide when to do what.  The main difference is that your motor control code now looks as simple as:

```
leftMotor.forward();
rightMotor.reverse();
```

or

```
leftMotor.stop();
rightMotor.forward();
rightMotor.speed(30);
```

You then end up with a program that is much cleaner and easier to follow.  And adding a third or forth motor is as simple as defining more Motor objects with their pins.

This video is a good introduction to what OOP is and how it differs from the "traditional" approach:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTfWr7o7Q4U